# Plurality of numbers between -1 and 1

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, numbers

If I recall correctly, the Académie française states that, for French, quantities comprised within [-1,1] are singular, and anything else is plural. This means, for instance, that we should say (in French) 0.3722 apple, instead of 0.3722 apples.

I know the plurality for 1 and -1 in English, but what is the plurality of real numbers between them?

Comment: Are you asking about (-1)? I've never heard or read something like "I have -1 [something] in my bag" for example... Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Alenanno, You understood correctly. Good contexts for this kind of use are statistics and measurements, like "the average household has 0.62 dog(s?)" or "it's -0.76 degree(s?) Celsius outside".

Comment: @zneak: Ah ok, I didn't considered technical use ahah my bad. :)

Comment: Related: [0.25 mile or 0.25 miles?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/0-25-mile-or-0-25-miles)

Comment: @RegDwight I understand the similitude, but the question doesn't cover negative values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is -1 singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural)

Comment: Curious. I've always heard -1 read with the singular. Perhaps it's a regional thing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could make the argument that English does not have singular and plural markers per se, but rather singular and "non-singular".  (I'm not necessarily advocating this view, just throwing it out there.)

The evidence would be that the singular form is used to refer to one of something, while the plural form is used to refer to all other amounts.  This includes everything between -1 and 1 (not including 1, of course).

- -25 volts
- -1 volts
- -0.25 volts
- 0 volts
- 0.1 volts
- 0.5 volts
- 0.999 volts
- 1.0000001 volts
- 1 volt

With that said, there are a few special cases that need to be addressed:

> 1. There is **no apple** on the table.
> 2. There are **no apples** on the table.
> 3. There is **half of an apple** on the table.

While (2) might be more common, (1) is certainly possible in certain situations. This looks like an exception to the rule; note that (1) is normally said in response to an assertion that an apple should be on the table, while (2) is said in any situation.

Now, (3) might look like an exception as well, but grammatically speaking, *apple* is still referring to one apple, where "half of an apple" = "half of one apple" (logically and syntactically).

Comment: However it should be noted that one would say 'You have 0.5 apples' and 'You have half an apple'.

Comment: I rather like this *singular* / *non-singular* idea. In some ways it seems 'non-singular' is in fact the *generic*, and we only use the singular when there really is *one and only one*. So for *What's in Mom's pie?*, the answer is likely to be *Apple*. Not *Apples*, even if it's a *huge* pie.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In that example, though, *apple* refers to the substance of apples, the meat, which is a (slightly) different thing with the same name.

Comment: @Toby Allen: I thought I did note that in my answer — special case #3. The *apple* part in "half an apple" is a red herring, because it is its own separate prepositional phrase (with *of* elided).  Notice that you say "two halves of *an apple*", pluralizing *halves* even though it equals 1 apple, and you say "4 halves of *an apple*", still not pluralizing *apple*, even though you now have two apples.  You're not counting apples in any of these examples, you're counting *halves*. Thus, if you combine the terms into a single compound word, "half apple", then you *do* get "two half apples".

Comment: It seems the definition of *plural*, when applied to the English language, is precisely "a value other than the default quantity of a noun, which is typically one" (taken from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural)). So we don't need to define this "non-singular" concept: it would be irrelevant, since it has the same meaning as "plural" in this context.

Comment: @rsenna: Well, the line before that in Wikipedia is "...plurality or [a] plural is a concept of quantity (i.e., grammatical number) representing a value of *more-than-one*." So, it's not "precisely" what you claim. But in any case, I actually do agree with you. "Non-singular" is just an arbitrary label I was suggesting to make a point, namely that "plural" doesn't only refer to more-than-one in English; I don't think there really is a problem just using the word "plural" in practice.

Comment: @rsenna: Thanks for that. I think what you've said is what I would have said if I'd thunk it thru and been a bit more articulate.

Answer (score 14):

In science and engineering you would use the plural

0.123 kilogram **s** or -0.1 volt **s**

Interestingly you use the plural for zero, so 0 volt **s**

Comment: Yep. The rule is that you only use the singular for **one** (1). Everything else, including decimals, fractions, zero, and negative numbers, takes the plural.

Comment: note that SI states that [*A plural of a symbol must not be used; e.g., 25 kg, not 25 kgs.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#General_rules)

Comment: @phuclv - good point, though that is a different grammatical rule. If you "speak it as the full word", you will add the "s", when appropriate. One reason not to include it in the symbol, is that it gets confusing - because "s" might be a valid letter that is part of some different symbol.