# One and a half minute/minutes

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, measuring-units

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”, “20 pound note”, “10 mile run”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run)
>   [Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile)

When talking about "one and a half" of any object, do we use the subsequent noun in plural or just singular? I'm aware that "A minute and a half" is also correct but I'm looking for the specific "One and a half"-construction here.

So for example, which of the below phrases is correct?

> You're one and a half **minutes** late!

or

> You're one and a half **minute** late!

Is there any difference when using the phrase as an adjective like so: "One-and-a-half-minute recipe"?

Comment: General Reference - Googling "**one and a half**", it's easy to see without leaving the Google homepage that wherever these words are followed by a noun, it's always in the plural.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got that far. Try Googling for `"one and a half minute"`, it'll yield a great number of results as well. Which is exactly why I'm asking. My gut feeling tells me to use the plural as well.

Comment: I guess. The difference is certainly a lot clearer on a [Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+and+a+half+minute%2Cone+and+a+half+minutes&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Or Google "**one and a half hour**", and most of the top 10 results are actually concerned with explaining why this is wrong.

Comment: Also [Plurality of numbers between -1 and 1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/plurality-of-numbers-between-1-and-1/21799#21799)

Comment: @FumbleFingers et al. - 1.5 is not between -1 and 1.  "Duplicate" is harsh.  Also, Google search results are not an authoritative source.  It would be enough to cross-reference to the similar answer.

Comment: I never said it was a "duplicate" - per my comment, I think it's "general reference". And whatever you think of Google as an "authoritative source", you must surely recognise some significance in the fact that the quotated search term "*one and a half **minutes** late*" returns 42,500 results - whereas "*one and a half **minute** late*" returns only **9 results** (one of which is this very question!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "one and a half" you are referencing *more than one* minute, so you must use the plural form "minutes".

Comment: Except perhaps for a single *sesquiminute*. :)

Comment: Is there any difference when using the phrase as an adjective like so: "One-and-a-half-minute recipe"?

Comment: @BloodPhilia: The expression *one-and-a-half-minute* is a "composite adjective", which invariably uses the singular (and no - I can't explain why that is! :)

Comment: @BloodPhilia Indeed there is. Those sorts of things are always in the singular: a two-day drive, a four-week course, a five-month delay, a nine-year absence.

Comment: @tchrist,BloodPhilia: It's "sorta" covered by [this earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/), but I can't derive a definitive principle from anything posted there.