# A word for more than one but less than 2

Tags: single-word-requests

"How many friends should I bring?  "you can bring one…….maybe '1 1/2' friends."   The question was "plural" so is answered in a "plural" form, but logically refers to "singular" (=1).

A single word that could refer to the (implied) integer between 1 and 2.

Comment: Not meaning to be picky, but there is no integer between 1 and 2. Integers are whole numbers.

Comment: Hi, Tom, and welcome to EL&U. IF I'm understanding this correctly, you are looking for an adjective or modifier that implies this situation that indicates something between singular and plural? I don't think that's possible. Something is either singular, plural, or unquantifiable in number.

Comment: The question is likely to be closed as indecipherable as it stands. Wouldn't 'How many pies have you eaten?' be more sensible? And then there are previous threads covering this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One and a half minute/minutes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/one-and-a-half-minute-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

This would generally be expressed in the plural. In fact, all numbers other than one will be plural, which the caveat that "one quarter of a pie" is singular, while "0.25 pies" is plural.

(Though "1 1/2 friends" is fairly nonsensical for the specific case. "1 or 2 friends" would be more likely, though the original answer could be considered cute, I suppose. "2 1/2 children" is a classic expression for the number of children in average families, but only when it's meant to be taken as an average. None of the families in town have 2.5 children, but they can have 2.5 children on average.)