# Each question carries 0.5 marks vs Each question carries 0.5 mark

Tags: grammar

Which one is right and why? Does the answer change if instead of 0.5 we have let say 5.

Comment: Please see *[Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/)* and *[Plurality of numbers between -1 and 1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21792)* among others.

Answer (score 1):

'0.5 marks' is normal. '0.5 mark' would be unusual. If you wanted to be strict and pedantic you might write '0.5 of a mark', but most people wouldn't. "Half a mark" is also very common.

Answer (score 0):

If we refer strictly to dictionary -one of the meanings is-

An appraisal; a **rating**. Often used in the plural: earned high **marks** from her superiors.

Also used to indicate various grades of academic achievement: got a **mark** of 95 instead of 100.

I can say .....Each question carrries 0.5 (% weightage) marks.

Comment: At least in UK usage, marks are indeed the weighting for a question, but not necessarily a percentage.

Comment: #DJClayworth Sure, so would it be correct to say "Each question carrries 0.5 % weightage.

Comment: That would be a grammatically correct sentence, though not necessarily meaning the same as the OPs original sentence.

Answer (score -3):

Are you trying to say that each question is worth half a percentage point? If so, why not just say it that way?

Further explanation:

"carries" is weird, because one doesn't think of a question being the kind of thing that has arms and can move a heavy item from one place to another. It just isn't the right metaphor.

"mark" is also weird. I know that you can say, especially in Britain, that somebody got "good marks" on a test. But it looks to me like that's a generic usage where "mark" = "grade". And you can't say that a question is worth half a grade.

Comment: 'mark' is perfectly normal usage in the UK for the number of 'points' awarded for a correct answer. 0.5 marks is only equivalent to 0.5% if the test is out of 100.

Comment: So you can say: "Question one is worth 1 mark, Question 2 is worth square root of two marks, Question 3 is worth pi marks." Can a student ask, of some particular test, "How many marks is this worth?"

Comment: And in Germany, getting marks for a correct answer is an economic stimulus.

Comment: @shane Yes, absolutely you can say that, or ask that. (Leaving aside the issues with non-rational numbers).

Comment: In that case, the right answer to my ear would be ".5 of a mark" as you note above.