# Is it proper to say "I earned -1 points today" when I lost 1 point?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, numbers

Suppose I play a game where I can lose points as well as gain them. Usually I'll say:

> I earned 10 points today, hooray!

But what if I lost points and still want to use "optimistic" verb?

> I earned -1 points today, bummer

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: The only grammatical issue here is whether -1 demands singular or plural.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz good point! -1 is still a single point, only negative. Was it asked before here on this site? :)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz well, it [was already asked and answered](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9735/11875).

Comment: Whose answer did you downvote today? *Suspicious* That's the only way to earn -1 points!

Comment: @Gigili lol! Actually my motivation was this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AstQr.png (so yes, I downvoted some answer on the Movies site ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is grammatically fine. There is no rule of *grammar* that says you can't earn a negative point. Some may argue it doesn't make logical sense, though I think it's fine logically as well.