# "More than one" is to "plural" as "less than one" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, numbers, analogy

We call the quantity of more than one (singular) *plural*. Is there any general word similar to this for a quantity less than one (singular)?

Comment: You're not comparing like with like. The term 'plural' is usually taken to refer to **integers** above 1. Numbers less than one cannot belong to the set of positive integers. And 'quantities' usually refers to non-negatives. So, as Andrew says, you're into fractions, but these do not compare with the singular / plural concept.

Comment: ... and *grammatically* speaking, plural is anything that is not singular, and only 1 is singular. So plural is *everything* else, including 1.00001, 0.99999, 0, and for some speakers −1 as well.

Comment: ... This is only a contrivance, an attempt to tie in grammatical usage with the notions involved. '3 - 4j' is part of 'everything else' in the field of number, and I'm pretty sure it has never been described as 'grammatically plural'. Grammar and reality / philosophy don't always fit together neatly. One pie is / two pies are // 0.3 pies are // no pie is / 0 pies are // -3 pies are // 3 miles is (usually).

Answer (score 3):

An amount less than one is a *fraction* and its adjectival form is **fractional**.

Comment: But that also applies to non-whole-number amounts greater than one, as well. It is not an antonym of 'plural' as was being asked.

Comment: @WS2 This is the answer to the question which was asked at the time I answered it. And even now, it still answers the body of the question, although the title has been edited.

Comment: Well understood .

Comment: This is the answer anyway … in my experience, people use *fractional* frequently for amounts less than one, and are substantially less likely to use it for non-whole-number amounts greater than one.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, in terms of grammatical number, English has only *singular* for when there is 1 or -1 of something, and *plural* for all other numbers.

Some other languages have forms for particular numbers other than those, and indeed English shows a trace of a dual number in words like *both* and some ways of treating *neither*, but only a trace as phrases using them will still be otherwise using just singular and plural.

Outside of grammar, for numbers between zero and one specifically, we have *fractional*. There are also several terms equivalent in form to *singular* that are more specific about the number (*dual*, *trial*, *quadral*).

Comment: +1, though we have a [dedicated question on whether −1 is actually plural as well](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural).

Comment: @RegDwigнt where it seems people mostly agree with me, so grand.

Answer (score 0):

`More than one` to `plural` is like `less than one` to `zero` or `nothing`.

Because `More than one dog` is at least two dogs, but `less than one dog` is no dog. 
Only `one` describes the `singular`

Mathematically `less than one` is from `]-infinite,1[` , but mathematically you don't call `more than one` plural