# What exactly is the definition of "plural"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I used to think plural meant 2+, but what about "0.5 hours"?

Is it more accurate to say "0.5 hour"? I don't think that's right, so my definition of "plural" must be inaccurate.

Even "0 days" seems more accurate than "0 day".

Google's definition shows **denoting more than one, or more than two**. That seems clearly inaccurate.

Does plural mean any amount other than exactly 1? Or what is a more accurate definition?

Comment: You can see the answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2139/187793) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9735/187793)

Comment: ["The only number that is singular is one. All other numbers are plural, including negative one. 1.0001 is plural. 0.99999 is plural. 0 is plural. -1 is plural. Only 1 is singular. The nature of singularity is being single, unitary, unique, isn't it? Everything else is plural."](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9796/300) So yeah. The definition you've arrived at is precisely right. (As far as English is concerned, of course. Other languages do things of their own with numbers, and many even make a distinction between more different categories than just "singular" and "plural").