# Using a comma before “and we already have a toaster.”

Tags: commas, conjunctions, clauses, comma-splices

Which of the following is correct?

1. No gifts please, we don't need any orchids and we already have a toaster.
2. No gifts please, we don't need any orchids ***,*** and we already have a toaster.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but this sentence, if added to the bottom of an invitation, sounds like something between rudeness and humour, doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes. Actually it may sound a bit arrogant to me too. Like saying whatever you may get us, it is either going to be useless, or something of little value (you poor beggar! :-) ), which we already have. A bit rude, as the meaning of a gift is often just the thought, not its material value. If I read that I would think: "I was not going to get you anything anyway"  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Neither one of your sentences is correct: you are attempting to splice together two independent clauses using a comma alone, which is a big no-no.

Try these instead:

1. No gifts please. We don’t need any orchids and we already have a toaster.
2. No gifts please; we don’t need any orchids and we already have a toaster.
3. No gifts please: we don’t need any orchids and we already have a toaster.
4. No gifts please. We don’t need any orchids. And we already have a toaster.
5. No gifts please. We don’t need any orchids, and we already have a toaster.
6. No gifts please; we don’t need any orchids, and we already have a toaster.
7. No gifts please: we don’t need any orchids, and we already have a toaster.
8. No gifts please. We don’t need any orchids. And we already have a toaster.
9. No gifts please: we don’t need any orchids. And we already have a toaster.
10. No gifts please. We don’t need any orchids — and we already have a toaster.
11. No gifts please; we don’t need any orchids — and we already have a toaster.
12. No gifts please: we don’t need any orchids — and we already have a toaster.

Comment: Though how big a no-no is open to question [Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/comspliceterm.htm): 'Though often treated as errors in traditional grammar, comma splices may be used deliberately to create a rhetorical effect of speed, excitement, informality, or confusion.' '"This is the error beloved of composition teachers--easy to identify, just what we need to separate the sheep from the goats. But is it as clear-cut as we tend to think? ...

Comment: ... The distinction between an impermissible comma splice and a legitimate juncture involving a comma is far less precise, for example, than that between a complete sentence and a fragment."
(Anne Klinck)' "The air was soggy, the season was exhausted."
(John Updike, "Hub Fans Bid Kid Adieu," 1960) // And compounding offences: 'No Sex Please, We're British'.

Comment: Excuse me (non-native). Is it ok to start a sentence, after a full stop, with an "And": And we already have a toaster. To me looks a little weird. Is this  fine in English ?

Comment: @Pam [It can be, yes](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16976). JRR Tolkien, a chaired professor of English, does so 1,667 times across *The Hobbit, The Lord of the Rings,* and *The Silmarillion*.

Comment: Thank you  tchrist. And... an upvote well deserved!  :-)