# Is it Correct To Start A Sentence With a Coordinate Conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, sentence-starts, is-it-a-rule

This seems to be argued back and forth by my Writing and Reading teachers. Here is the problem. For example I write this sentence:

> And I went to bed to get some sleep.

Just a simple sentence with the conjunction `And` at the beginning. My teachers disagree whether this is correct or not. So is it correct to start a sentence with a coordinate conjunction?

This is not a duplicate because my question is about all the FANBOYS, not just the conjunction "and".

Comment: Yes, it's correct. [Related.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192294/what-great-writers-have-used-coordinating-conjunctions-at-the-start-of-sentences)

Comment: Where did that come from?!

Comment: The past, young padawan. That question came [from the past](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKYQ5ibxslI).

Comment: But of course it is! And quotes by great authors will support your position in class.

Comment: No, it is not. Read the new edit.

Comment: Yes this a dupicate. And your whole FANBOYS thing is a myth, too.

Comment: I'm a seventh grader. Do you really expect me to think that FANBOYS is a myth?

Comment: I said all conjunctions! I ain't need a duplicate for every single one!

Comment: It is arguable that a string starting with a coordinator should not be called a sentence. But it is certainly not ungrammatical per se to use sentence fragments. And used in moderation, they can improve style. However, the classification of _for_ in particular as a coordinator is considered unacceptable by some, and _neither_, _only_ are further candidates. All this has been covered here before.

Comment: If you're a seventh grader who can't be expected to accept that the 'FANBOYS' treatment is a vast over-simplification, I'm not sure why you're asking your question on a website intended for 'linguists ... and serious English language enthusiasts'.

Comment: It is because I am new in the US! You can't expect a person who moved into the US a few months ago to know all the rules. I come here to understand English better!

Comment: The trouble is that you will very probably get answers on ELU that your teachers won't accept. And you'll find that there often isn't one agreed correct answer.

Comment: @PythonMaster "You can't expect a person who moved into the US a few months ago to know all the rules" Oh, you'd be surprised- there's really no upper limit to what I can expect.

Comment: But how can it be wrong?  For, personally, I make it a policy to begin all my sentences with conjunctions, whenever possible.  Since it makes the prose sort of flow along, I find.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: in fiction.

No: in formal/academic papers, or in many non-fiction books.

Thomas Pynchon is one of the greatest American novelists and a great stylist. You'll find in his work:

> "Bigger, not softer, **ése. And** speaking of lunch, how about
> tomorrow at Vineland Lanes?"
>
> Zoyd had played a few mob weddings in his career, nothing the kid
> couldn't handle, and besides the eats would more than make up for any
> awkward episodes, so it wasn't as if he were running a mean trick on
> his daughter's boyfriend, whom he was still not 100 percent crazy
> about, or anything like **that. And** as a problem to be addressed,
> Isaiah was more like a vacation from deeper difficulties, chief among
> which, all of a sudden, was the recrudescence of Hector Zuñiga in
> Zoyd's life, a topic, as he lit a joint and settled in front of the
> soundless Tube, that his thoughts unavoidably found their way back to.
>
> [Vineland](https://books.google.com/books?id=0RJSBwAAQBAJ), by Thomas Pynchon

Also, see:

> [A Grammar Book for You and I-- Oops, Me!: All the Grammar](https://books.google.ca/books?id=KHp1kMdSJ8MC&pg=PA157#v=onepage&q&f=false) ... C.
> Edward Good - 2002
> **When you exercise your new writing muscles and use conjunctions to start sentences, make certain you do not put a comma immediately after
> the conjunction.**

the section that starts with

> **Never Start a Sequence with a Conjunction**
> Poppycock, on p. 157

which includes comments from the great stylists of the past, such as Fowler and Follett.

The most exhaustive essay on the matter that I know is:

> [Garner on Language and Writing: Selected Essays and Speeches of Bryan A. Garner](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9_PdSrVNTUUC&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q&f=false)   By Bryan A. Garner. See:
> **On Conjunctions as Sequence Starters** at p. 63

Garner being the preeminent style expert of our time, IMO.

I'd strongly suggest to at least peruse it.

Comment: I do not agree that the practice of beginning sentences with *And* is unsuitable for formal academic writing. Just for instance, classicists tend to be some of the greatest sticklers for correctness in English, and yet I find the redoubtable Paul Shorey, of the University of Chicago, beginning 10 sentences thus in the 16 pages of his 1909 article “Φύσις, Μελέτη, Ἐπιστήμη” *(Transactions and Proceedings of the American Philological Association [TAPA]* 40:185–201). I myself have begun many a sentence thus in scholarly publications and never had an editor question it.

Comment: @Brian Donovan. My experience is this varies with the editorial board, thus I'd strongly recommend that any author should get acquainted with the rules of the respective ''house.'' Anyway, I've added at the end of my answer a link to an essay by Bryan Garner on the matter, which provides a plethora of  examples.