# Preposing construction: "This I know"

Tags: word-order, fronting

> "This I know today, but back then..."

What does this word order show? What's the rule?

Comment: probably - unaware of this in past

Comment: The word order shows nothing.  It's just a "theatrical" way to reinforce the distinction between now and then.

Comment: "This I know" instead of "I know this" puts more emphasis on "this."

Comment: It has an 'Old Fashioned' feel, maybe to imply old-fashioned values.

Comment: What makes you think there's some "rule"?

Comment: Your example uses **preposing**, a type of noncanonical word order: a type of information packaging construction. Preposing has pragmatic constraints--which could probably be considered to be pragmatic "rules". Quite a bit of stuff has been written on this topic of preposing and the pragmatics related to it. :)

Answer (score 5):

In "This I know" there  is no subject-verb inversion. Inversion would be This know I or better, as Jonathan says below: This do I know.

"this" is placed at the beginning of the sentence which is called fronting. 
The word in unusual position gets more emphasis or dynamic.

You should change your headline. Maybe: This I know. Inversion or fronting?

Comment: You are correct.  [OSV is not inversion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/256756/2085).  One merely fronts the O to give it more emphasis. This was once done more frequently, but it is still used.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be an inversion, it should have been written like this: "This do I know"... as a question. We use it to stress the feeling of saying the phrase, among other reasons.