# What is the meaning of 'wottest'?

Tags: etymology, verbs, archaicisms, early-modern-english

I am interested in early versions of English, and while reading I've often encountered the word *wottest* being used. For example:

> Then he said, "Galahad, son, **wottest** thou what I hold between my hands?"
>   "Nay," said Sir Galahad, "but if ye tell me."
>   "This is," said he, "the holy dish wherein I eat the lamb on Shrove-Thursday... *Malory's History of King Arthur and the Quest of the Holy Grail*, Sir Thomas Mallory

[Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=wottest) has no entry for "wottest".

My questions are these: What does it mean? When do we use it (if it is still used today)?

Comment: It is the second person singular present form of [*wit*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wit) (to know): "Wottest thou not what to do?" - "Do you not know what to do?"

Comment: @Mick That'a impressive. How about an answer to that effect?

Comment: @RichardKayser It's finding supporting information. I'm trying to find references for the tenses and persons.

Comment: Is this not just Googleable?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I'm having trouble finding detailed information on the verb. The tenses must be tabulated somewhere.

Comment: *Wottest* is Early Modern English. Old English had *wast* there. This smells like General Reference to me.

Comment: @tchrist It would be good to have links to usable and reliable information about this period of English -- verb forms, etc. So far, I have not found any useful info with Google. Maybe this question can be moved to ELU meta at some point.

Comment: See a simple Google search for [wottest define](https://www.google.com/search?q=wottest+define)

Comment: The simple answer is that 'wottest' is not Old English, but rather late Middle English or, at a stretch not supported by many scholars, Early Modern English. In Middle English, the meaning is still quite close to 'have seen' and thus 'know'; 'wot' generally is *a variant form* of 'wit', which latter is still in use in limited contexts, to wit, this one; it is otherwise archaic, and 'wot' is entirely obsolete. In the particular text cited, however, 'wottest' is used as an archaism for atmosphere in a translation to Modern English from a Middle English adaptation of Old-Middle French writings.

Comment: Looking at the history of the question, I see that some of the problems were the result of a liberal re-interpretation of the question in the first edits (not the OP's). I will endeavor to reverse those problems with another edit.

Answer (score 3):

It is the second person singular present form of [*wit*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wit) (to know): "Wottest thou not what to do?" - "Do you not know what to do?"

Comment: That's interesting (and obviously correct), but how does one go from *wit* to *wottest*?

Comment: I will try to flesh this answer out with more info as and when I can find it. Should we turn it into a Wiki and move it to meta?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: [Nay, thou wost not thine own skill in healing. It shall not be so.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/256756/2085)

Comment: [Shakespeare’s use of *wot*](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Headwords-Instance.aspx?Ref=7655)

Comment: @Medica As Mick said, it's the second person singular (which we don't use any more) of the irregular verb **to wit** (which is also obsolete). The present tense of **to wit** is: I wot, thou **wottest**, he/she/it wotteth, we wot, ye wot, you wot, they wot. It's similar to **to walk** except that **to walk** is regular: I walk, _thou walkest_, he/she/it _walketh_ (but that has changed to walks), we walk, _ye walk_, you walk, they walk. The italics indicate obsolete parts of the verb.

Comment: @BoldBen - My question was not exactly that, but that's interesting, so thanks. I was more wondering why *to wit* was not, *I wit, you wit, thou wittest...* etc..

Comment: @BoldBen No, it is **not** "he/she/it wotteth" my goodness! [*Wot* is the third-personal singular indicative of *to wit*.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wit#Conjugation)

Comment: @tchrist Sorry, 'wist' of course. "The first doe he shot at he missed/ the second one he trimmed he kissed/ the third one went where nobody wist/ among the leaves so green-o" I should've known better

Comment: @tchrist is correct, BoldBen 'wist' is past tense. The present tense of 'to wit' for he/she is 'wot'