# What is the type of English used in the King James Bible called?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing-style

In the King James Version (KJV) of the Bible, there is a distinct type of English present (this passage from Job 1:7-12):

> And the LORD said unto Satan, Whence comest thou? Then Satan answered the LORD, and said, From going to and fro in the earth, and from walking up and down in it.
>
> 8 And the LORD said unto Satan, Hast thou considered my servant Job, that there is none like him in the earth, a perfect and an upright man, one that feareth God, and escheweth evil?
>
> 9 Then Satan answered the LORD, and said, Doth Job fear God for nought?
>
> 10 Hast not thou made an hedge about him, and about his house, and about all that he hath on every side? thou hast blessed the work of his hands, and his substance is increased in the land.
>
> 11 But put forth thine hand now, and touch all that he hath, and he will curse thee to thy face.
>
> 12 And the LORD said unto Satan, Behold, all that he hath is in thy power; only upon himself put not forth thine hand. So Satan went forth from the presence of the LORD.

([source](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Job-Chapter-1/))

There are specific words used from (old? middle?) English, like *unto*, *thou*, *whence*, *comest*, *fro*, *hast*, and the ending certain words with *-eth*, like *feareth*, and *escheweth*.

There are modern writings that tend to imitate this style of writing, as an example, this "[Ten Commandments of Writing an IMAP client](https://www.washington.edu/imap/documentation/commndmt.txt.html)":

> 1. Thou shalt not assume that it is alright to open multiple IMAP
>    sessions selected on the same mailbox simultaneously, lest thou face
>    the righteous wrath of mail stores that doth not permit such access.
>    Instead, thou shalt labor mightily, even unto having to use thy brain
>    to thinketh the matter through, such that thy client use existing
>    sessions that are already open.

Which brings me to my question: I'd like to critique this writing style and refer to it, but I don't know what it's called.  What is the type of English used in the KJV called, and (if it's the same — or even if it isn't), what's the writing style used to parrot the KJV writing style called?   It can be referred to in a single word or a phrase — I'm just interested in making sure I use the right terminology in referring to it.

Comment: Try [writing.se] Good Luck.

Comment: You may find this article https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-12205084
 of interest. By the way, I don't regard 'to and fro' as archaic. (Even though the spellchecker doesn't like 'fro'!)

Comment: @Kris What is the difference in the focus of Writing vs. English Stack Exchange (what would make that site a better target to ask this question? I'm pretty unfamiliar with either site, and so this would help me better understand the focus).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker What you're critiquing there is an **ungrammatical parody** of the Early Modern English from the AV/KJV. As a certain professor of English once advised, [learn to discriminate between the bogus and genuine antique – as you would if you hoped not to be cheated by a dealer!](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/256756/2085)

Comment: Generically, it's a [facetious] ***mock-archaic*** style.

Comment: The phrase "literary style" made me think you were asking about *voicing*, i.e. first person, third person, etc. The 'which form of English' would never have entered my mind as a form of literary style since one can write any sort of story in early English that sounds completely different from the way the Bible phrases things. I don't mean to suggest this use is wrong in any way - it's just unconventional to me. That could be why @Kris suggested the Writing site.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I'll assume you're referring to either Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade or to Monty Python and the Holy Grail? I'm a big Indiana Jones fan, but have never seen Monty Python and the Holy Grail.

Comment: Yes, the Monty Python, specifically the holy hand grenade of Antioch scene: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM9Bynjh2Lk), [script](http://www.montypython.net/scripts/HG-handgrenade.php).

Comment: The printing and spelling in King James (Authorized Version) bibles that have been in common use for over 100 years was *very much different* than the first ones produced in 1611. Today, those are very hard for us to read for that reason. Keep that in mind.

Comment: If someone can help me understand why the votes to close are there for "doing more research"? I'm not sure how much more research could actually be done.  What actionable advice can you give to make that close reason invalid in this case?

Comment: To some extent the order of words in the King James were kept a lot closer to the Geek/Hebrew then moden translation.  Also many people would not have had any experience of written English before hearing the King James read out.

Comment: King James Bible English would be my answer (I'm not a scholar in this field)

Comment: Similar to "mock-archaic" (or "mock-biblical"), you might also want to use "faux-archaic" / "faux-biblical". "faux-" means "fake" and is often used to describe when something is trying to look like something it isn't (e.g. written in the 1600s). Though I wouldn't use it if my intended audience was too unsophisticated -- using a direct French borrow like "faux" can make it seem like you're a bit pretentious.

Comment: @JosephDoggie I have heard it called "King James English", although often in a humorous context such as "If King James English was good enough for Jesus, it's good enough for me."

Answer (score 71):

The KJV is written in [Early Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English) (not [Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) or [Old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) English).

Styles that imitate this use **archaic** English, which the Oxford English Dictionary describes as:

> Belonging to an earlier period, no longer in common use, though still retained either by individuals, or generally, for special purposes, poetical, liturgical, etc. Thus the pronunciation *obleege* is archaic in the first case; the pronoun *thou* in the second.

*Archaic* is how dictionaries like Lexico (also by Oxford) describe *[unto](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unto)* and *[shalt](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shalt)*.

(You’ll also see some words marked *obsolete* in the dictionary. The [difference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whats-the-difference-between-archaic-and-obsolete) between *archaic* and *obsolete* is that obsolete words aren’t used anymore.)

Comment: Good! I'd also note that the KJV featured some uses considered archaic even at the time of publication, as Barber discusses in [his book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Early_Modern_English.html?id=d8VZAAAAMAAJ). (A few examples: the use of words like "verily," of older idioms as opposed to more modern ones, keeping the thou/you distinction rather than reverting to a generic *you*.) In comparison, the Geneva Bible published 50 years before is often easier for modern English readers to follow, since it uses fewer archaisms and less Latinate diction.

Comment: The KJV was published 1611. The advent of modern English doesn't have any one date, but it was 1550 at the latest. While it is "hard" to read at times, it is not "impossible,"  which Middle or Old English would be. +1 for a definitely correct answer.

Comment: The thou/you distinction was still in pretty common use at the time the KJV was written. It was just at the very start of the process of disappearing then, and didn't become (nigh) ubiquitous until the early 1700s, I'd say. "verily" definitely wasn't archaic for the time. It's archaic now, but not obsolete.

Comment: I'd publish a list of obsolete words but to do that I'd have to use them. Then they wouldn't be obsolete anymore.

Comment: One usage which the KJV adopts, but was old-fashioned when the KJV was published, is the -eth ending on third-person singular verbs, which the OP notes.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin  many (most?) people (including preachers) think that the capitalized words should be emphasised (`the LORD said`). In fact, they indicate differences in translation between the Geneva bible and the new KJV. Source: [God's Secretaries: The Making of the King James Bible](https://www.amazon.com/Gods-Secretaries-Making-James-Bible/dp/0060838736) which is a great and easy read

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: I don't think "verily" would have been considered archaic in 1611, since it appears quite often in Shakespeare's plays, including "The Tempest", dated to 1611.

Comment: @jamesqf Fair. I may have mixed archaism and formal register on that point, or being old and having an older sound to it. *Verily* was on the decline in the seventeenth century but still fairly common; it had broadly Biblical and Puritan connotations. [Helen Bromhead](https://books.google.com/books?id=P25KH3J0mMwC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=verily+seventeenth+century&source=bl&ots=DURAZV5q3c&sig=ACfU3U0-IfbuVtFagQ3eHOb_8bY-aEDgJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP17Dc_cHlAhVrTd8KHdfdCj8Q6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a great chapter on the word.

Comment: This wouldn't fit the Writing.SE, but Literature.SE, Christianity.SE, and Linguistics.SE would all be good places -- possibly each would have a different slant on the answer as well: examining it as a piece of writing, as an expression of faith, and as an expression of a specific point in the English language.

Comment: Forsooth, an upvote I cast unto thee.

Comment: @Noldorin The thou/you distinction was current well into the early 1900s: "Who told thee to do that?" "Why, thou didst!", "Don't thee thou me, lad!" Source: My grandfather, who was the lad in about 1920.

Comment: @Ben Sure, but it was only dialectal after the early 1700s really. Standard English ceased to use it then; it only really appeared in poetry, mock archaic, and regional language.

Answer (score 46):

Supplementary to [Ray Butterworth's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516710/what-is-the-literary-style-used-in-the-king-james-bible-called/516715#516715):

If you speak of this as the 'Biblical' style, and the modern parodies as 'Mock-Biblical', people will understand you.

[As @Laurel says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516710/what-is-the-literary-style-used-in-the-king-james-bible-called/516711#516711), the underlying English dialect is Early Modern English; but you need to realize as well that the Authorized Version is a *translation* which seeks to reflect both the various styles employed in the Hebrew and Greek originals and a literary tradition of Biblical translation stretching back two hundred years in English (and beyond that to the 4th-century Latin Vulgate). The 'Biblical' style was already established and familiar to its readers when the AV was first published: both the AV and its Catholic competitor the Douai-Rheims translation were stylistically based on the earlier work of Tyndale (1525), which hearkens back to Wycliffe's Middle English translations.

The theological authority of the AV carried over to its style, which dominated religious translation and expression in English for the next three centuries. The style was followed not only by translators of the Hebrew-Greek scriptures and works from other religious traditions such as the Quran and the Upanishads, but also by new works claiming religious authority, such as Joseph Smith's Book of Mormon and Aleister Crowley's Thelemist texts.

The Biblical style is so widespread that it's immediately recognized by virtually all English speakers, and is thus eminently suited to parody.

Comment: [AND there are certain stylistic or rhetorical quirks from the original Hebrew](http://www.tyndale.org/reformj01/weitzman.html) preserved in many translations. These include the device of beginning successive sentences with AND for one. For another, there's the special Hebrew tense pattern/structure that in the Vulgate works out to pairs like *expectans expectavit*, so a progressive element like a participle combined with a perfect/praeterite/past echoing that but completed: *Awaiting, I awaited* scenarios.

Comment: @tchrist Oh, yes .. And some of those were not 'preserved' but introduced by the translators under a misunderstanding of BH grammar.  That *and*, for instance, the initial *wa-* particle, is usually not *and* but a morphological prefix marking a particular conjugation of the verb.

Comment: Yes. The 1662 Anglican *Book of Common Prayer*, which together with the AV is often seen as one of the glories of the English language, relies in same way you describe upon its predecessors - the 1549 and 1559 versions - in the use of Biblical English. The interesting thing is that the German reformer, Martin Bucer, who, invited by Thomas Cranmer, to advise the English church on its liturgy, didn't actually speak English. But it seems clear to a lay person, such as me, that it borrows from the same Biblical English.

Comment: @WS2 For your rereading pleasure, please see the final section on “Special Effects” at the end of [this posting](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/192346/2085) for a particularly well-regarded and “authentic” recreation of the language of the AV/KJV in modern literature, here specifically the language of the Psalms.

Answer (score 30):

The King James Bible was written in the same place and at the same time as Shakespeare's plays, but the styles of these two works are very different.

Shakespearean style requires a much larger vocabulary to understand and uses much more complicated sentence structure.
The Biblical style is mostly simple words in easy to follow sentences.
Shakespeare's works contain 31,534 different words, while the Old Testament and New Testament contain only 10,867 and 6,063 different words each (and a large number of those are proper nouns naming specific people and places).

So the style you refer to is not simply because of where and when it was written.
Referring to it as "Elizabethan" or "Early Modern English" is misleading.

I'd simply call it "biblical" style.

And I'd say the given quotation is written in "mock biblical" style, especially since it is such a poor attempt at copying biblical style:

- Until recently "alright" didn't even exist as a word.
- "doth" is third person *singular*, but here it is used with a *plural* subject.
- many verbs appear in modern form and aren't conjugated with "-t" (2<sup>nd</sup> person) or "-th" (3<sup>rd</sup> person) suffixes.

Comment: Could the difference in style be put down to the difference between prose vs. poetic forms at the time?

Comment: Doesn't poetry commonly use a much larger vocabulary that prose though?

Comment: The vocabulary in the old testament (in Hebrew) is also very limited.

Comment: It also makes the mistake that always drives me nuts with faux archaic English and uses "thinketh" as thought it were an infinitive.

Answer (score 5):

How about [Elizabethan](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=when%20was%20the%20reign%20of%20Elizabeth%20I%2C%20queen%20of%20England%2C)?

> Elizabeth I (7 September 1533 – 24 March 1603) was Queen of England
>   and Ireland from 17 November 1558 until her death on 24 March 1603.
>   Sometimes called the Virgin Queen, Gloriana or Good Queen Bess,
>   Elizabeth was the last of the five monarchs of the House of Tudor.

Just for fun, check out [this article](https://www.wappingersschools.org/cms/lib/NY01001463/Centricity/Domain/1504/Elizabethan_language.pdf) for ways in which you can become conversant in Elizabethan English. Here's a fairly long excerpt:

> 2Sounding Funny Is Fun!  (No, really, it's actually a blast)The
>   biggest changes from our modern tongue come in the vowels.  You
>   remember kindergarten, right?  A-E-I-O-U and Sometimes Y?  In the
>   English language, the vowels are the most flexible sounds, bending and
>   morphing around the consonants they are framed with.  In Elizabethan
>   English, the vowels are the sounds that are the most different from
>   our modern accent.   Some pronunciations stay the same (we love
>   those!) and some change.
>
> Let's start at the top.  We'll give the letter - or the sound -  and
>   examples of how that letter sounds in our modern accent, then explain
>   the differences: Vowels A - cat, hat This version of the a, the short
>   a, is basically the same.  It is drawn out a bit, held onto just a
>   little... caaat, haaat. A - father, walking This short a changes to a
>   flat a like in "pant".  So father rhymes with rather, walk sounds like
>   whack. A - take, make, stable This long a becomes an eh sound.  So
>   take sounds like tek, make sounds like mek, stable like steble.  Funny
>   huh? E - head, dead The eh sound of these words becomes an ay or ai
>   sound.  So head and dead rhyme with braid. I and Y - lie, die, my, by
>   The long i sound becomes an uh-ee sound.  If you say my really really
>   slowly, it sounds like m-ah-ee... instead, we're going to say m-uh-ee.
>   This isn't oi like Yiddish!  Lie sounds like l-uh-ee, die sounds like
>   d-uh-ee, my sounds like m-uh-ee, by sounds like b-uh-ee.I - hit The
>   short i stays the same (yay!) and rhymes with it. O - come This one
>   becomes much darker and rounder...  almost au sound.
>
> You can almost throw in a uh sound too.  So come becomes coom, of
>   becomes uh-oov.U - cup, cut The short u sound combines with the "oo"
>   sound, like "coop".  If the short u and the oo sound had babies,
>   that's what the short u  should sound like.  So cup becomes coop,
>   cutbecomes coot. Let's add an R  3The r in Elizabethan English is more
>   exaggerated, a hard r, but isn't quite the pirate "ARRRR!", or a
>   rolled r.  It's a consonant you can really chew on... never be afraid
>   to lean on it and draw it out a little. ER - mercy This sound rhymes
>   with air, and the r is emphasized.  Mercy becomes maircy, terse sounds
>   like tairce, curse becomes cairse. OR - Lord This takes on a very
>   round mouth shape and the short o is almost an "oo" sound.
>
> Lord becomes loord, ford becomes foord. The Diphthong! Diphthongs are
>   not what happens when women wearing low rise jeans and thong underoos
>   sit down.  Rather, they are vowel combinations...  In modern English,
>   we usually shorten diphthongs to one quick sound...  Elizabethan
>   English usually uses both letters.  After all, why would you put both
>   in if they weren’t to be used?  There is one exception, but that will
>   be pointed out below. AI - fair In this case, both letters are
>   pronounced.  The a is a short a  and the i is like the Elizabethan i. 
>   The r is hard, and a little exaggerated (but not rolled or the pirate
>   rrrrrr).  So "fair" becomes fah-ay-err. AY - say Pronounce both
>   letters - so saay-ee. EI - either This is the diphthong exception.  It
>   becomes an "ay" sound, so either becomes ayther. OU - mouse Pronounce
>   both letters, so mouse becomes muh-oose.  Not "moose"...   round out
>   the ou sound and make it darker.  House becomes huh-oose. OW - brown
>   This is very similar to the OU - the W is afer all, a double u.Brown
>   becomes bruh-oon. . . ..
>
> Most of the consonants stay the same.  There are a few, however, that
>   do change. C - precious Modern English has turned the "cious" letter
>   combination into "shun".  We're going to turn the c into an s, and
>   then say the rest of the letters.  Precious sounds like preh-see-uhs,
>   musician sounds like myu-zih-see-un. G and V - speaking, ever  4The G
>   that appears at the ends of words can be dropped.  Likewise, the V in
>   the middle of words can often be dropped as well.  This is especially
>   appropriate for lower class characters.  Speaking becomes speakin',
>   listening becomes listenin', ever becomes e'er, evenbecomes e'en. 
>   Lower classes might even drop the v in heaven, making hea'en.H - hoop
>   Every H is spoken (think Pygmalion, which was retold as My Fair Lady).
>   Hoop is never oop, but always spoken with the letter H.  Hand, heavy,
>   hark, all use the H. K - knight
>
> Modern English has turned the leading K in words like knight and knife
>   silent.  At this time, it was sometimes spoken, especially by the
>   lower classes.  Knight becomes kuh-night, knife becomes kuh-nife. R -
>   art Remember the R from "lord"?  Same deal... lean on it a little! 
>   Chew on it and enjoy it... R's are very fun to say. Arrrt! (Ok, that's
>   a little piratey) S - compassion The double S, and sometimes single S,
>   has become a sh sound in modern times.  However, back in the day it
>   was spoken as a hard s... instead of compashun, we're going to say
>   comp-ah-see-ion, and instead of surely pronounced serly, it becomes
>   soor-ly. T - righteous Like the S, sometimes a T isn't a T - it's a
>   CH.  Nowadays we say richus, but in Elizabethan speak we'd say each
>   letter and get ri-tee-ous.  Pastures goes from  paschurs to pas-toors.

Comment: Seems to me the sound changes are pretty much irrelevant to the literary style.

Comment: True that. I did, however, preface the lengthy excerpt by saying "just for fun." Don

Comment: @StoneyB Not necessarily, in a work that was designed to be read aloud publicly, and likely to be heard by many people who were illiterate.

Comment: @alephzero James' panels undoubtedly had excellent ears for the cadences of the spoken language; but the literary style persisted through subsequent sound changes and through spoken realization in scores of dialects.

Comment: That article doesn't work in my accent. For example, the "a" in "father" and in "walking" are _very_ different from one another!

Comment: Upvoted this, although I think technically its an anachronisim to call art produced during the reign of King James "Elizabethan" (technically its supposed to be *[Jacobean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobean_era)*). Still, its just an off-by-one error. :-)

Comment: You say that the KJV is written in Elizabethan English when it was translated after her reign. To an extent this is (inadvertently?) correct, e.g. in the use of thee/thou/thy to refer to God, which had almost completely fallen out of use by this time. According to Alister McGrath (ISBN-13: 978-0385722162) this was retained because "The King's translators were forbidden to depart to any significant extent from the text of the Bishops' Bible of 1568", in turn based on the Great Bible of 1539. As English had changed greatly in this time, the language of the KGV was old-fashioned when it appeared.

Comment: @David: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is not one "writing style" for the King James Bible, per se. It was written by at least dozens of authors over thousands of years in multiple different languages, none of which were English. Due to the different authors and different languages they used, there are many writing styles within the Bible (regardless of version) and they are quite different from each other, even within a given version.

The *language* into which the King James Bible was translated is [Elizabethan English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Elizabethan_English), which is from the early portion of modern English. The works of Shakespeare also fall into this period of English.

Actual [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) and [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) are much farther from what we'd recognize as English today, with the former's usage ending around the 11th century and the latter's usage ending around the 15th century. The King James Version of the Bible was translated and published in the early 17th century, with work beginning in 1604 and publication in 1611.

Comment: The first paragraph doesn't describe the King James Bible (‘Authorised Version’); it describes its _sources_.

Comment: @gidds I would say that it describes both. The King James Bible is not a new work that merely cites sources, but rather a _translation_ of an existing work (or a collection of existing works, depending on how you want to look at it.) The 'writing style' is, thus, more a function of the original authors and the languages in which they were writing than of the translators and their language. As a result, the writing style varies significantly from one part of the KJV to another.

Comment: But the elements of the "style" identified in the question are language differences arising from changes in English over the last 308 years.  The disparate styles present in the source are not responsible for that, and style differences from one part of the bible to another are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @phoog The question asked about 'writing style,' but, as you note, the highlighted differences are language differences, not writing style differences. Thus, I answered both questions and tried to point out the distinction.

Comment: Regretfully, I feel I have to bestow a rare downvote here. This post drastically undervalues the contribution of a translation and translators (and their source selection) to how a Bible translation reads. This fact is easily evident to *anyone* simply by going to Bible Gateway, picking a verse, and then changing the dropdown for translation several times.  In the process, it does a grave disservice to amazing (arguably never since equaled) work that was done by the KJV translators.

Answer (score 3):

Early Modern, or Elizabethan, English, is also commonly called “Shakespearean,” although William Shakespeare’s writing is less formal and more humorous.  You will often, for example, see the speech patterns of Marvel Comics’ Thor called “Shakespearean English.”