# Can you begin a sentence with "but"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

Is it grammatically possible to begin a sentence with "but" ?

Comment: "But soft, what light through yonder window breaks?"

Comment: " 'Tis but a wisp of winter moons, summoned softly by the stars."

Comment: Top result on Google: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction

Comment: But  me no buts.

Comment: But of course you can! (Related question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192294/what-great-writers-have-used-coordinating-conjunctions-at-the-start-of-sentences).)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/but), the following case (but it is not the only valid case) may apply

> ***But for + reason***
>
> But for is used to introduce the reason why something didn’t happen:
>
> *But for the traffic, I would have been here an hour ago. (The traffic was very heavy – if it weren’t for the traffic, I’d have been here an hour ago.)*
>
> *They would have been badly injured but for the fact that they were wearing seat belts. (They were wearing seat belts – if it weren’t for the fact that they were wearing seat belts, they would have been badly injured.)*

Comment: But wait, there are many more cases than that one that are "allowed" ...

Comment: But I could find no sources for other possibilities so far.

Comment: The point is, you don't really need a source to validate every utterance. The best stylists in English (cf. Shakespeare, above) have begun sentences with conjunctions since, well, there was an English language.

Comment: @Robusto I agree, but am I then not running the risk of not being authoritative? I don't have enough experience in these matters to feel comfortable putting things out there without an anchorage. Do you have any advice on the matter?

Comment: Saying "the following case is allowed" is tantamount to saying "except for this one case, all other cases are *not* allowed." This makes your statement prescriptive, and on this site we tend to plump more for freedom of expression.

Comment: @Robusto That was not my intention. How could I rectify this?

Comment: Use the case you listed as an example of the usage, just make sure you're not implying it's the only one. And welcome to EL&U. ^_^