# Starting sentences with coordinating conjunctions

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it incorrect to start a sentence with “and”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593/why-is-it-incorrect-to-start-a-sentence-with-and)

Is it acceptable to use coordinating conjunctions to start a sentence in standard English?

> ...should not be left to a subgroup. And everybody must perform a final runthrough.

I have seen opinions both for and against this practice, and am unsure as to the agreed custom.