# Can I use "but" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

For a while, using *but* to start a sentence was largely frowned upon. But, I think it is possible to use *but* at the beginning of a sentence, as long as it isn't overused.

Am I right?

Comment: Related: [is it acceptable to start a sentence with "however"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79/is-it-acceptable-to-start-a-sentence-with-however)

Comment: Please note that people saying it is possible below are able to provide authoritative references.  "People are entitled to their own opinions.  They are not entitled to their own facts."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

But for conditional usage, I would still tend to frown upon it. But, used sparingly, it can be effective in emphasizing the thought or action behind the "but".

Comment: But then again it could just be used just for the sake of it.

Comment: This answer is meta.

Comment: In the first sentence, "but" is a synonym for "except".

Comment: @Karl: But that doesn't invalidate the usage.

Comment: Please note that the word 'But' in the answer is used in two different meanings in the first sentence and in the second one. c.f. http://books.google.co.il/books?id=CZXcTzFLDuwC&lpg=PA76&ots=FVoWY5WH8l&dq=contrastive%20conjunctions%20aval%20ela&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q=contrastive%20conjunctions%20aval%20ela&f=false

Comment: Capitalizing the second "but" looks terribly wrong to me.  The coordinating conjunction should be part of the sentence containing the independent clause.

Comment: -1 Please see FAQ on answering.

Comment: @Kris Why? Did I not "Always be polite and have fun"?

Answer (score 16):

It is not ‘grammatically incorrect’ and it is not restricted to informal writing. When *but*  occurs at the beginning of a sentence it is not to be construed as a conjunction, but as a conjunct. Conjuncts are adverbs which, in the words of ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’,

> . . . play a cohesive role between separate sentences, or clauses. They . .
>   . express logical relationships such as addition, contrast and
>   causation.

Comment: Could you please provide an example that illustrates its use as a conjunct?

Comment: @Lynn: Here’s one taken at random from ‘Europe: A History’, a magisterial academic work by the eminent historian Norman Davies: ‘Mozart thrived in the relaxed social climate of the 1780s, which the growth of the “opera buffa” reflected. He struck a neutral stance towards the morals of his day. But the Rake’s “Reward” is too melodramatic to be taken seriously . . .’ Here’s another: ‘Germany was indeed obliged to assist its Austrian ally, if Austria had been attacked. But Austria had not been attacked . . .’

Comment: Correct. The standard injunction to avoid using conjunctions (or conjuncts) at the beginning of a sentence was predicated on the assumption that such sentences tended to be fragments. In fact, as this matter has subsequently been reviewed over the past 60 years or so, the concern has been found to be wholly unwarranted. The so-called "rule" is a shibboleth and can be ignored as being an exemplar of Ted Bernstein's "Miss Thistlebottom's Hobgoblins."

Comment: Maybe off the topic at hand: This indirectly suggests to new writers that one way would be to mechanically replace all such instances of initial '*But*' with '*However,*' -- does that resolve the issue? (As I said, this may be a separate question.)

Comment: @Kris: I see absolutely no need to do so, and, in any case, _however_ may not always be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I used to think it wrong to start a sentence with *But*. My English teacher told us not to say or write that way, though he admitted that in reality many did use that way.

I am very familiar with Longman Contemporary English Dictionary. In it, four parts of speech are given if we search for *but*. They are conjunction, preposition, adverb and noun. Yet when we want to start a sentence with *but*, we use its conjunction meaning. That is grammatically incorrect.

Barrie England wrote it was a conjunct (adverb) and referred to *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage*. If so, that well explains.

However, I see such usage is not in many dictionaries. That means it is not universally accepted. As a non-native English user, I will avoid using it this way.

Comment: It's reclassified by many now as either a 'conjunct' (CGEU) or a 'pragmatic marker subclasses sentence connector; contrast marker'. Believe it or not, sentence connectors usually occur at the start of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

In a narrative I can see no reason not to use it, however it is still wrong in most aspects of written English.

Seeing a 'but' at the start of a sentence would make me want to see what on earth had come before...

Comment: Which shows you jumped over there.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use "but" at the beginning of a sentence. The supposed rule against this practice is an urban myth. I used to offer my college students $100 in cash if they could find this "rule" in a reputable grammar book. Nobody ever collected the money! What's more - all the grammar books feature sentences starting with "but." 
To read more: http://wp.me/PU98s-2B