# Can 'But', 'And', or 'So' be used to start a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it really incorrect to start a sentence with “and”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593/is-it-really-incorrect-to-start-a-sentence-with-and)
>   [Is there any valid rule discouraging the use of a certain word to start a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/is-there-any-valid-rule-discouraging-the-use-of-a-certain-word-to-start-a-senten)
>   [Usage of “And” in the beginning of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/usage-of-and-in-the-beginning-of-a-sentence)
>   [Can I use "but" at the beginning of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48974/can-i-use-but-yet)

I heard that "but, and, so" are not supposed to be used at the beginning of a sentence.

I have noticed, however, a lot of sentences use "but, and, so" as the first word of the sentence.

Are the words at the beginning of the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It all depends on the sentence. And whether it's going to be published or just written to a friend. But I wouldn't worry about such things, because there are lots of such silly "rules" that are actually "non-rules" but merely prescriptions by language commentators who have strong biases that they believe everyone must follow. So, when you hear or read about what one can and can't do when writing and speaking English, be suspicious.

Comment: I wish people here would stop downvoting questions like this from non-native speakers of English. It's really unfriendly and biased. The OP needs assistance, not disapproval. If you want to close the question because it's a duplicate, that's certainly reasonable and I would support such a move, but **it's a real question** that keeps popping up and apparently can't be answered often enough.

Comment: Also, some 'rules' seem liable to change even within the lifespan of the average downvoter.

Comment: And when you *do* put a conjunction at the head of a sentence or clause, please do not put a comma after it—which you're also all too likely to see and which is not acceptable.

Comment: @StoneyB: Except, of course, when that comma separates a parenthetical remark that is also a subordinate clause. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke  Yes; but, however enamoured you may be of high-Victorian style, and, I might add, whatever patina of profundity it may lend your utterances, or, indeed, bestow upon your literary reputation--where was I?--oh, yes, but that is a construction of which you should avail yourself only with discretion and circumspection.

Comment: @StoneyB: Agreed. Context is all. Discretion and circumspection are the better parts of palaver on paper. And all's well that ends well, saith the Prophet (or was that Polonius?).